# How to add our own gestures in android?

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am working on the gestures concept.  I want know some thing about how to add our own gestures in android.For example if user drawn "O" symbol i want to make some events.  Please share some tutorials and Snippet  of the code.

Comment: the android SDK provide a sample application does what you need. just click on new \ project \ android from samples and find the gesture example

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few results available with a relatively simple Google search. I would normally post a sarcastic comment or something. :-)

But this isn't quite an everyday subject if you would, so I have here a few links that should get you started. But you should work on your Google *foo* too. ;-)

1. http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/Gestures-in-Android
2. http://www.hascode.com/2010/05/creating-a-simple-gesture-app-with-android/
3. http://code.google.com/p/quickdroid/source/checkout (QuickDroid Checkout)
4. http://code.google.com/p/quickdroid/source/browse/ (QuickDroid Browse code)
5. http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/working-with-gesture-api-in-android/

I found the 5th link a little more promising. Of course, I haven't seen too much of it for that to be definite. But try them all anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Check the link below which will guide on how to create our own gestures and use it.

1) [Link 1](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGestures/article.html)
 2) [Link 2](http://code.google.com/p/android-gesture-recognition-tool/)
 3) [Link 3](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/01/10/working-with-gesture-api-in-android/)
 4) [Link 4](http://www.hascode.com/2010/05/creating-a-simple-gesture-app-with-android/)

Go throug some of the links you will surely get some idea about gestures.